# React - Splitting children into parts

Tags: reactjs, react-native

#### The Idea

I'm trying to create a component that is being split up in to parts.

E.g. in the example code below, I aimed to have the Form and the Actions separated while maintaining state. This way, I can create a basic Form + action button component, and then style it differently on different pages.

```
import  { useState } from 'react'

const FormBasic = ({ children }) => {
  const [ text, setText ] = useState('')

  const onSubmit = () => console.log("Submitting");
  const onChange = (e) => {
    console.log("Typing", e.target.value);
    setText(e.target.value)
  }

  const Form = () => <textarea rows={4} onChange={onChange} value={text} />;

  const Actions = () => <button onClick={onSubmit}>Some Buttons</button>;

  return children({ Form, Actions });
};

export default FormBasic;
```

#### The Problem

I will then be using it this way (below). The thing is - it all renders just fine for static components, but you will start seeing problems the moment state changes.

E.g. When I type in the `<textarea />` and `onChanged` is triggered, the function rerenders and you loses focus to the text area. So end up you cannot really type in the text area.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
      <FormBasic> 
      {({ Form, Actions }) => {
          return (<React.Fragment>
                  <div style={{ border: '1px solid red'}}>
                    <Form />
                  </div>
                  <div style={{ border: '1px solid blue'}}>
                     <Actions />
                  </div>
            </React.Fragment>)

      }}

      </FormBasic>
  );

}
```

I'm including a code sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-brook-nrrbf?file=/src/App.js

#### The Question

There may be questions about the practical use of this kind of component. Practically aside, how may I modify my codes so that I can continue to use the state inside the exported `textarea`.

Or are there other forms of exporting a component so that I can split them and maintaining the state?

Or is the above style possible at all?

PS: I've used context and redux, and I am trying not to use them in this example. I am trying to keep it simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution to your problem is: instead of passing `text` and `setText` as props, to use the React [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API.

Specifically:

- `FormBasic` would become the state + context provider.
- `Form` and `Actions` would become the context consumers.
- The context would contain the state + the state setter.

Here's what I came up with ([working example on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-68630654-tnxwk?file=/src/App.js)):

(I used more generic names for the state variables to help other readers of this post).

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useContext, createContext } from "react";

// create the context with some generic defaults
const StateContext = createContext({
  state: "",
  setState: v => v
});

// create the context hook
const useStateContext = () => useContext(StateContext);

// the textarea component
const Form = () => {
  const { state, setState } = useStateContext();

  const onChange = (e) => {
    console.log("Typing", e.target.value);
    setState(e.target.value);
  };

  return <textarea rows={4} onChange={onChange} value={state} />;
};

// the buttons component
const Actions = () => {
  const { state } = useStateContext();

  const onSubmit = () => {
    alert(state);
  };

  return <button onClick={onSubmit}>Some Buttons</button>;
};

// the form itself holding state and the context provider
const FormBasic = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState("");

  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={{ state, setState }}>
      {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <FormBasic>
      <div style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}>
        <Form />
      </div>
      <div style={{ border: "1px solid blue" }}>
        <Actions />
      </div>
    </FormBasic>
  );
};
```

Notice that `FormBasic` no longer needs to have `children` as a function, or the content wrapped in `React.Fragment`, making the code cleaner. You can use the context consumers directly.

Comment: What happens if I have multiple <FormBasic /> running on the same page, will the Context be shared? Or will they be separated unique store since each of them have their own provider? I'm asking because I wish to have each component maintaining it's own state instead of a centralized store. Hence I'm trying to avoid context and redux.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial they will each have their own state because they use different contexts. I've updated the CodeSandbox example to demonstrate this.

Comment: So may I conclude any children using useStateContext in `individual instance` of StateContext.Provider will have their own state. Even though They declare the createContext exactly the same way.

Comment: Yes, state is contained in and provided by the individual `<StateContext.Provider>` components. All the children of a `<StateContext.Provider>` share the same state. You have as many states as you have `<StateContext.Provider>`s in your JSX. To use an OOP analogy, running `const StateContext = createContext(/* ... */);` is like declaring a class, while invoking `<StateContext.Provider>` is like instantiating the class as an object.